# Python. Поиск и замена подстрок в строке

Tags: python, алгоритм, замена

Смысл заключается в том что к примеру имеется строка:

`aaabbcdecvvv`

Имеются подстроки:

`aa = 1`

`aaa = 2`

`bb = 3`

`b = 4`

`c = 5`

`cde = 6`

`vvv = 7`

Необходимо заменять содержимое строки на подстроки с начала и по максимальному совпадению.

Следовательно как результат будет `2bbcdecvvv` -> `23cdecvvv` -> `236cvvv` -> `2365vvv` -> `23657`

Метод который знаю, а именно `replace` не подходит, т.к. он вырывает не всегда из начала

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
repl_dict = {"aa":1, "aaa":2, "bb":3, "b":4, "c":5, "cde":6, "vvv":7}

a = "aaabbcdecvvv"

for i in sorted(repl_dict.keys(), key=len, reverse=True):
    a = a.replace(i, str(repl_dict[i]))
    
print(a)  # 23657
```

Answer (score 2):

Пжлст)

```
stroka = 'aaabbcdecvvv'

for x in stroka:
    if 'aaa' in stroka:
        stroka = stroka.replace('aaa', '2')

    elif 'aa' in stroka:
        stroka = stroka.replace('aa', '1')

    elif 'bb' in stroka:
        stroka = stroka.replace('bb', '3')

    elif 'b' in stroka:
        stroka = stroka.replace('b', '4')

    elif 'cde' in stroka:
        stroka = stroka.replace('cde', '6')

    elif 'c' in stroka:
        stroka = stroka.replace('c', '5')

    elif 'vvv' in stroka:
        stroka = stroka.replace('vvv', '7')

    print(stroka)
```

EDIT:
Что бы не было повторения добавьте

```
elif 'vvv' in stroka:
    stroka = stroka.replace('vvv', '7')
    try:
        print(int(stroka))
        break
    except Exception:
        pass
        
print(stroka)
```

Вместо

```
elif 'vvv' in stroka:
    stroka = stroka.replace('vvv', '7')
    
print(stroka)
```

Answer (score 1):

Как более короткий вариант по сравнению с `if` через регулярки:

```py
import re 

txt = "aaabbcdecvvv"

words = {"aaa" : "2",
"aa": "1",
"bb" : "3",
"b": "4",
"cde" : "6"} # И так далее

for i in words:
    txt = re.sub(i, words[i], txt)

print(txt)
```

Единственное условие что что в словаре `'aaa'` должно идти перед `'а'`. Но это верно и для конструкции `if` - `else`